# lodash deep peeking with _.get()

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a data structure like this

```
var data = {
  'app.state1': {
    some: {...},
    sequences: [
      {...},
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
  },
  'app.state2': {
    some: {...},
    sequences: [
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
  }
};
```

And I want to get `sequences` at index `0` for `data['app.state1']`

I tried to achieve it like this

```
var seq = _.get(data, 
   'data[' + currentState + '].sequences[' + currentSequence +']');
```

or like this

```
var seq = _.get(data, 
   'data[\'' + currentState + '\'].sequences[' + currentSequence +']');
```

both do not work... The problem I believe in `currentState` which is string with the dots inside (`app.state1` or `app.state1.substate2` e.g.). Any thoughts guys?

Answer (score 2):

You combine to much, check this:

```
var seq = _.get(data, [currentState, 'sequences', currentSequence]);
```

Comment: Great! I've missed that the `path` could be an array.  Thanks!